# Where to get boost/python.hpp?

Tags: python, boost

I found some project used python.hpp as `#include<boost/python.hpp>`, but this file is not included in the project, where can I get this file? I have done some basic search but didn't get the answer.

Comment: Basic search of boost/python.hpp in google givs a HOWTO and the library as the first 2 hits

Comment: @Mark and now it gives this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download boost here:

```
http://www.boost.org/
```

On linux distributions, usually packages exist:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-python1.42-dev
```

or just install all:

```
sudo apt-get install boost-1-47-0 libboost-all-dev
```